# Load the page and completely and display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good Morning every one. I need a web page to load completely and then display. I do not want to load them in parts. The page should be rendered fully and displayed to the user. I tried some code. But its delaying the load for specified time and then loading the page from the start. This is taking more time than usual. Please help me with this issue.
Thank you in advance..:-)

Comment: This is almost never a good idea, and it's almost always bad UX.

Comment: Ya.I got it.But the client is requesting like that. I duno what is the reason..:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many ways

1. Using `window.location.href`

   window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
2. Using window.open

   window.open('http://www.google.com');
3. Using **[jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** to load throug ajax.

   In html

   ```
   <div id="divID" > </div>
   ```

   In javascript

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#divID').load('YourFolder/test.html');
   });
   ```

Comment: I thought load (when used like that) was meant to handle AJAx requests, which means that the user will get to the page THEN make a request for the content, which might be what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Let me try this..:)

Comment: no actually i do not not want the user to request. As the page contains many elements it is taking time to load and loading in pieces. so I need them to load completely and then display it to user..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

on your body tag:

```
<body style="opacity:0;">


<script>
    window.onload = function(){
       document.body.style.opacity = 1; 
    }
</script>
```

You can also you, style.display (block or none)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide everything using some css:

```
//some_div
{
  display: none;
}
```

and then in javascript assign a function to document.onload to remove that div.

I think this is a really bad idea. Users like to see progress, plain and simple. Keeping the page at one state for a few seconds and then instantly displaying the loaded page will make the user feel like nothing is happening and you are likely to lose visits.

One option is to show a loading status on your page while stuff processes in the background, but this is normally reserved for when the site is actually doing processing on user input.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
CSS
body { visibility: hidden; }

JS
$(window).load(function () {
  $('body').css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Of course you can get more fancy and use CSS3 transitions or animate with opacity, it depends on how fancy you want to get

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div id="loader">Loading...</div>
    <div id="wrapper" style="display:none">
      HTML content
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:** (using jQuery)

```
$(window).load(function () {
    alert('Content Loaded');        
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#wrapper').show();
})​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gWuCa/1/

Comment: Its not working. In the body i have js along with html content. Is that the reason why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things here,

1, Document is ready, Dom is Ready to be managed.
2, Images are Downloaded ..  So complete Document is ready

First thing you will be able to do using jquery  ready function
second one  there are jquery plugins.. so uisng that image  is loaded  plugin
you will be able to do this

Stopping  any user action  while  these load happens can be done  in multiple way
1, you can hide the body  until  everything is loaded(Doc+image)
2, you can put an overlay gray with wait indicator, so that user wont be able to do any actions

Thanks

Comment: @Kowshik   if an answer make sense for ... you should Accept the answer :)

Comment: oh...I am new to this..In my last question also one of the member told to accept..May I know where to do that?